# Why can't Bundler locate this gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, mechanize, bundler

Why can't **bundler** locate the Mechanize gem?

The following is in my Rails project's Gemfile:

```
gem 'mechanize', :git => 'git://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize.git'
```

Running bundle install throws the following error:

```
Updating git://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'mechanize (>= 0)' in git://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'mechanize (>= 0)'
```

I arrived at this problem after forking the project to make some small changes, but was not able to get bundler to use the github location nor a local path. Why is it that it cannot locate the gem?

If I remove all instructions and simply do `gem 'mechanize'` then it works flawlessly.

---

**Versions:** Bundler 1.0.14 + Rails 3.1 Release Canditate + Ruby 1.8.7 (via RVM) + Debian 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as though [the project is missing a gemspec and one won't be getting added.](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/issues/101)

You should be able to clone the project into your vendor/gems directory. You will need to create a mechanize.gemspec file, too.
You would then require it in your Gemfile using something like.

```
gem 'mechanize',            :path => 'vendor/gems/mechanize'
```

Comment: I cloned it into my gems directory, how do I use it in my application?

Comment: Alternatively, you could also fork and provide your own gemspec

Answer (score 1):

I have seen older version of bundler having issues with git:// like urls.

Have you tried updating bundler; or replacing git:// with http:// ?

Comment: No luck pulling from the http link. Bundler is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this thread in the future, here's what I did to make it work..

I forked the project, made my changes then ran the following to generate a .gemspec:

```
rake debug_gem | grep -v "(in " > `basename \`pwd\``.gemspec
```

I had to make a slight modification because the gemspec was trying to include a .gemtest file which did not exist.

I then modified my Gemfile to source from the path:

```
gem 'mechanize', :path => '/my_rails_app/vendor/gems/mechanize'
```

I then ran **bundle install** and everything went through without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Use version explicitly. They don't support unreleased versions, so they delete gemspec file.

```
gem 'mechanize', '2.0.1'
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, i changed by adding gem version in between name and path.

> gem 'image_core', '0.0.1', :path => './lib/engine/image_core'